# Increase database value by one [Error Message] Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Firstly, I am receiving the Error message

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

I am using a repeater to create many Events within the database, and each Event contains EvtName, EvtType, EvtDescription, EvtDate, and EvtVote. EvtVote is stored as an int and I have a button called "eventButton" and each time it is clicked, the EvtVote should be updated by one. However, when I click the button, the error message appears. Here is the code that creates this.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeaterEvent">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="jumbotron">

            <h2><asp:Label ID="lblEventTest" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EvtName") %>'></asp:Label></h2>
            <h3><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EvtType") %>'></asp:Label></h3>
            <h4><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EvtDate") %>'></asp:Label></h4>
            <h4><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EvtDescription") %>'></asp:Label></h4>   
            <h4><asp:Label runat="server">Amount Attending: </asp:Label>                           
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("EvtVote") %>'></asp:Label></h4>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="eventButton" Text="Attending" class="btn btn-primary" OnClick="EventVote_Click"/>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And here is the back-end code for the button.

```
public void EventVote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Events SET EvtVote = EvtVote + 1");
    loadDatabase(cmd);
}
```

Not sure what the error message is but any advice would be great.

Comment: It's not the source of your error but I would note that your query will increase the vote of EVERY event by 1, not just the one event associated with that button.

Comment: Ok thank you for this. I haven't gotten far enough to even test the query but I will have to look at a way to sort this out. Thank you

Comment: bind `repeaterEvent`  if  is not post back

Comment: thank you for this although I have no idea how to do this

Comment: The error message tells you that you're trying to postback something potentially dangerous. To allow it you'll have to turn it off as it says in the error message.

Comment: Add EnableEventValidation="false" in your page directive.

Comment: problem solved. Thank you

Comment: @Stuart you should write up the solution as an answer below and accept it. don't edit the question to mark it as "solved".

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I added the code:

```
EnableEventValidation="false"
```

to my page directive. It now looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Events.aspx.cs" Inherits="Website.Events" EnableEventValidation="false"%>
```